# RMD packages can't be downloaded in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I can't download the RMD packages in R studio. I tried it by running `install.packages("rmarkdown")`, and I tried it by `File > New File > R Markdown > Download packages`.

This is the output:

```
> install.packages("rmarkdown")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Luke/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘glue’, ‘stringi’, ‘knitr’, ‘yaml’, ‘stringr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
glue       1.0.0  1.3.1              TRUE
stringi    1.1.5  1.4.3              TRUE
knitr     1.15.1   1.23             FALSE
yaml      2.1.14  2.2.0              TRUE
stringr    1.2.0  1.4.0             FALSE
rmarkdown    1.4   1.13             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/glue_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 34947 bytes (34 KB)
downloaded 34 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_1.1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 14220135 bytes (13.6 MB)
downloaded 13.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/yaml_2.1.14.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 180051 bytes (175 KB)
downloaded 175 KB

package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘knitr’, ‘stringr’, ‘rmarkdown’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.23.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 880134 bytes (859 KB)
downloaded 859 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 135777 bytes (132 KB)
downloaded 132 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3155180 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'stringr' ...
** package 'stringr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'stringi' 1.1.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.7 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'stringr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Luke/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq/downloaded_packages/stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'stringr' is not available for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Luke/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq/downloaded_packages/knitr_1.23.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'knitr', 'stringr' are not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/Luke/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_1.13.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq\downloaded_packages’
```

The `C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq6rTgq\downloaded_packages` folder contains:

[Screenshot of named folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAcaf.jpg)

I am very inexperienced with programming in R, so I have no idea what to do with this. I am learning to do it (via the online Udacity course), and for that I need these RMD packages to continue. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: install.packages("glue", type="binary"). Try to install all dependencies as binary versions. Does that work?

Comment: @DSGym Thanks for your answer. I tried it with the missing packages, and indeed, now they also are in the named /downloaded_packages folder. But, when I try to open a .rmd file, I get the message: Creating R Markdown documents requires an updated version of the rmarkdown package. Do you want to install this package now? When I click 'yes' and when I try again to open the .rmd file, I get the same message that the updated version is required...

Comment: hm, try to unstall it with remove.packages and install it again. Also read this: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown

Comment: What R version are you using?  If it is 3.2.x, that's the cause of your problem:  packages for very old versions like that are not updated or made available as binaries.